# Is there a way to visualize log axis values as normal numbers?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some values in log scale and I already managed to do that as you can see in this example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0.2, 30, 1, 103, 950],
                   'y':[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]})

plt.plot(df['x'], df['y'])
plt.xscale('log')
```

[image]

Although I would like to change this type of visualization... I don't want to show values as powers of 10. I want to show something like [0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000] instead of [10-¹, 10°, 10¹, 10², 10³].

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ScalarFormatter()`:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['x'], df['y'])
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.ScalarFormatter())
```

Output:

[image]